# How to make volley calls synchronous

Tags: android, web-services, oauth, android-volley

In my application, I'm using volley for networking. Now the backend team have made some changes in web-service call, which is before every api call I need to call one more service(oauth service) which will provide access token in it's `JSON` response. This access token is then used in my actual service(login service) call as a query in url. Means I need to make two calls, one after the other.

Implemented this change in my code i.e For eg say login service: 
**step 1)** Call oauth service which gives access token.
**step 2)** Use this access token in url as a query for login service.

Now the problem is the calls are not in sync, I receive access token in  response after login call thus getting an error

**Login service call:**

```
 public void onClickLogin(View v) {
        // Tag used to cancel the request
        String tagJSONobj = "json_obj_req";

        String url;

            if(Constants.RUN_AUTH_API) {

                authAuthentication = new AuthAuthentication(tinyDB, SignInActivity.this);
                authAuthentication.getAuthToken();
                url = https://abc.xyz.com/Services/api/UserValidation/userValidate.do?access_token= + tinyDB.getString(Constants.MY_SHARED_PREF_AUTH_TOKEN);
            }else
            {
                url = Constants.SIGNIN_URL;
            }


            showDialog();

            JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
            try {
                object.put("userName", name);
                object.put("password", password);
                object.put("appType", "MOB APP");

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, object,
                    new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                            hidePDialog();

                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                    hidePDialog();
                    System.out.print("error is" + error.getMessage());
                    error.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(SignInActivity.this, getResources().getString(R.string.login_service_error_message), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }

            }) ;

            // Adding request to request queue
            AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq, tagJSONobj);
        }
    }
```

**OAuth service call:**

```
public class AuthAuthentication {
private static final String TAG = AuthAuthentication.class.getSimpleName();
private TinyDB tinyDB;
private Context context;

public AuthAuthentication(TinyDB tinyDB, Context context){
    this.tinyDB = tinyDB;
    this.context = context;
}

public void getAuthToken() {

    String tag_json_obj = "json_obj_req";
    String url = https://abc.xyz.com/Services/oauth/token?grant_type=password&client_id=restapp&client_secret=restapp&username=admin&password=admin";


    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
            url, "",
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                    try {
                        Log.d(TAG, " Response" + response.toString());
                        tinyDB.putString(Constants.MY_SHARED_PREF_AUTH_TOKEN, "" + response.getString(AppTags.TAG_AUTH_TOKEN));

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(context, context.getResources().getString(R.string.unable_to_process), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    // Adding request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq, tag_json_obj);

}
```

}

Comment: its very simple... just call your second volley onResponse method of first req

Comment: Could you please share some code

Comment: onclick of login coll oAuth method... oAuth method OnReponse call login method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call OAuthsevice firstly on login button click and OnResponse method call login Api

**OAuth service call:**

```
public class AuthAuthentication {
private static final String TAG = AuthAuthentication.class.getSimpleName();
private TinyDB tinyDB;
private Context context;

public AuthAuthentication(TinyDB tinyDB, Context context){
this.tinyDB = tinyDB;
this.context = context;
}

public void getAuthToken() {

String tag_json_obj = "json_obj_req";
String url = https://abc.xyz.com/Services/oauth/token?grant_type=password&client_id=restapp&client_secret=restapp&username=admin&password=admin";


JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
        url, "",
        new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                try {
                    Log.d(TAG, " Response" + response.toString());
                    tinyDB.putString(Constants.MY_SHARED_PREF_AUTH_TOKEN, "" + response.getString(AppTags.TAG_AUTH_TOKEN));
                    onClickLogin();/// here to peform login

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
        Toast.makeText(context, context.getResources().getString(R.string.unable_to_process), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});

// Adding request to request queue
AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq, tag_json_obj);

}
```

**UPDATE**

if OAUTH will call multiple time we need is OAUTH key for diferent API...

> Create This class in utility folder

```
public interface VolleyResponse {
   void processFinish(String output);
}
```

> just change you class constructor like this..

```
public class AuthAuthentication {
private static final String TAG = AuthAuthentication.class.getSimpleName();
private TinyDB tinyDB;
private Context context;
private VolleyResponse delegate;

public AuthAuthentication(TinyDB tinyDB, Context context,VolleyResponse delegate){
  this.tinyDB = tinyDB;
  this.context = context;
  this.delegate= delegate;
}
 --------
 -------
}
```

> In OnResponse method of AuthAuthentication class

```
@Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

            try {
                Log.d(TAG, " Response" + response.toString());
                tinyDB.putString(Constants.MY_SHARED_PREF_AUTH_TOKEN, "" + response.getString(AppTags.TAG_AUTH_TOKEN));
                //send response of volley 
                delegate.processFinish(tinyDB); //it will broadcast your response

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

> and use this as you want. suppose you have to use in login click

```
login.setOnClickListerner(new View.OnClickListenr(){
     @Override
     public void onClick(View view){
         AuthAuthentication auth= new AuthAuthentication(tinyDB,mContext,new VolleyResponse() {
                @Override
                public void processFinish(String output) {
                       //output conatins response
                       loginApicall();
                }

             }.getAuthToken(); ///if not work then auth.getAuthToken                  

    }
});
```

Comment: is there any other way because I have many api calls and I cannot write too many if statements in getAuthToken()

Comment: Why unticked my answer..?